# TextView inside TextSwitcher gravity bottom wont work

Tags: java, android, layout, textview

I have a standard `TextView` and `TextSwitcher`:

The TextView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:textColor="#3F51B5"
android:textSize="40sp"
android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
android:paddingLeft="4dp"
android:paddingRight="4dp"
android:background="@android:color/black">
```

The TextSwitcher:

```
<TextSwitcher
                    android:id="@+id/questionTextSwitcher"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"/>
```

The text of the `TextView` changes dynamically, and sometimes the text is a couple lines.

The black background is the `TextView`, and the white is the `TextSwitcher`:

When there is a longer text set it looks like this:
[image]

When there is a smaller text it looks like this:
[image]

I want the `TextView` to be placed at the `bottom` of the `TextSwitcher` - but that isn't happening?

Comment: Have you tried using layout_gravity instead of gravity?

Comment: yup still wont pin to bottom

Comment: OK.Try giving gravity to TextSwitcher as well

Comment: Still nothing...

Comment: try running it on real device

Comment: Can't this second but I will try...

Comment: "The black is the TextView, and the white is the TextSwitcher" ?? what you are trying to achieve! I can't see black and white color of the text here. post entire xml.

Comment: @Isaac have you ever got the chance to test it?

Comment: @Rahul Khurana didn't work

Comment: @Radhey I've updated my question please take a look.

Comment: please add entire xml file.

Answer (score 0):

try to match the parent height and also use the layout_gravity attribute.